# Screen environment variables do not transfer when calling screen with program

Tags: matlab, environment-variables, gnu-screen

I want to use 'screen' to call a program (Matlab) but with some specific environment variables. I have set the desired variable in .bashrc

```
export LD_PRELOAD=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libharfbuzz.so
```

Now when I start screen, the variable is transferred. After initializing a screen:

```
/data/jasper$ echo $LD_PRELOAD
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libharfbuzz.so
```

Then when starting Matlab, it works perfectly:

```
>> getenv('LD_PRELOAD')

ans =

/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libharfbuzz.so
```

Now the strange bit: When starting Matlab directly in a single screen command, it does not work:

```
screen matlab -nodisplay
```

from Matlab:

```
>> getenv('LD_PRELOAD')

ans = 

''
```

What went wrong and why?

Answer (score 2):

By trial and error I switched from setting the environment variable in .bashrc to setting it in .screenrc (using `setenv`). This worked.

Apparently, calling programs directly using screen bypasses bash and .bashrc does not get sourced. In contrast, .screenrc does get processed. This makes sense when you think about it.